# Error decoding Data Matrix that is base256 encoded with pylibdmtx

Tags: python, decode, barcode, datamatrix

I'm trying to successfully decode Data Matrix barcodes that are base256 encoded using pylibdmtx.  When the barcode contains a 0x00 byte the library seems to treat it as a string terminator (null) and ignores the rest of the data in the barcode.

Here is a snippet of code that will create a barcode and decode it:

```
from pylibdmtx.pylibdmtx import encode, decode
from PIL import Image

message = b'\x16\x05abc\x64\x00\x65\x66g'
print('message:',message)
barcode = encode(message)
img = Image.frombytes('RGB', (barcode.width, barcode.height), barcode.pixels)
# uncomment if you want to save the barcode to a file
#img.save('barcode.png')
decoded = decode(img)
print('decoded:',decoded)
print(' length:',len(decoded[0].data))
```

Here is the result:

```
message: b'\x16\x05abcd\x00efg'
decoded: [Decoded(data=b'\x16\x05abcd', rect=Rect(left=9, top=10, width=80, height=79))]
 length: 6
```

The created barcode reads properly with other online tools and dmtxread invoked from a command line.

Is there a limitation with the python wrappers for libdmtx or something I am doing wrong?

Other Info:

This is the simplest example I could come up with to illustrate the problem.  The barcodes are much larger and already in production systems.

I did try the python wrappers for the ZXing library and it did not even recognize many of the barcodes.  I am open to using other libraries.

Thank you.